# Can I have multiple entries under the same primary key while using DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm currently developing a skill which will be a Stock portfolio manager. 
I want the table to have three headings

1. UserID (which comes from Alexa)
2. Stock name
3. Stock amount

UserID is the primary key, and currently I can add an amount of a stock to the table and then in a separate method called GetPortfolioValue I query the database to return the Stock name and Stock amount for a specific UserID, which I will then do some maths on to return the Portfolio value.

The problem is, I can't add another entry under the primary key and so the portfolio can only have one Stock option in it, which sucks

I want to later be able to edit the portfolio in case a user sells part of their stocks.

Is there a way I can do this using DynamoDB?

Comment: Is there a one to many relationship between users and stocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primary keys must be unique. You probably need a compound primary key of UserID + Stock Name. In DynamoDB that is accomplished by setting UserID to the hash key, and Stock Name to the sort key, on the primary table index.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** have several items with same primary key when table has sort key. If table has only primary key without sort key - then no. If table has sort key, then each primary & sort keys combo must be unique.

[image]

In this table, PK attribute is primary key, SK - sort key.

[image]

Yet PKs will be placed physically together, there shouldn't be PKs like "active" & "not_active" while there are only 2 possible values for that row item and all of them will fall into only 2 spaces. If you will have a lot of rows with same primary key, you will create heat spot for queries and you may experience slow queries. But it's way too broad topic to discuss how to design DynamoDB table.

You will probably benefit from my article: https://lukasliesis.medium.com/learning-from-aws-fcb0cc71926b

There are two brilliant videos by [Rick Houlihan](https://www.linkedin.com/in/rickhoulihan) mentioned on DynamoDB Architecture:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yqfmXiZTlM

I highly recommend watching both for multiple times to get into mindset of DynamoDB, understand queries heat maps, how to put all app into single table and use DynamoDB to it's best.

**Update: Adaptive Capacity**

Probably most common issue which once **was** in DynamoDB.

> If you’ve used DynamoDB before, you’re probably aware that DynamoDB recommends building your application to deliver evenly distributed traffic for optimal performance. That is, your requests should be evenly distributed across your primary key. This is because before adaptive capacity, DynamoDB allocated read and write throughput evenly across partitions. For example, if you had a table capable of 400 writes per second (in other words, 400 write capacity units, or “WCUs”) distributed across four partitions, each partition would be allocated 100 WCUs. If you had a nonuniform workload with one partition receiving more than 100 writes per second (a hot partition), those requests might have returned a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException error.

Read full article here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/

Comment: great and complete answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you're using the userId from the requests from Alexa, they will provide an excellent primary key for your dynamoDB database.

```
"user": {
  "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.[unique-value-here]",
```

Simply store the stocks as a JSON object against each user.

```
{
  "stocks": [
    {
      "stockAmount": 45,
      "stockName": "AMZN"
    }
  ]
}
```

Storing the Object

```
DynamoDB dynamo = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(...)); 
Table stocks = dynamo.getTable("stocks");

String json = {"stocks": [{"stockAmount": 45,"stockName": "AMZN"}]}

Item item =
  new Item()
      .withPrimaryKey("alexa_id", 1)
      .withJSON("document", json);

table.putItem(item);
```

and how to get it back

```
DynamoDB dynamo = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(...)); 
Table table = dynamo.getTable("stocks"); 

Item documentItem =
  table.getItem(new GetItemSpec()
                .withPrimaryKey("alexa_id", 1)
                .withAttributesToGet("document"));

System.out.println(documentItem.getJSONPretty("document"));
```

As your users add or remove stocks you'll need to append to the stocks array for the user. You'll be subject to a 400KB limit for each of your DynamoDB items The size of a given item includes the attribute name (in UTF-8) and the attribute value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give that a go!

Comment: Another option would be to have a primary key of (userId, stockName) where userId is the hash key and stockName is the sort key. You could then retrieve all stocks for the user by querying by userId and the amount of each stock by querying by userId and stockName. You would also not be restricted by the 400KB item limit size